# Active Directory LDIF attributeSchema update

Tags: active-directory, ldif

I have about 80 Schema Attributes I need to add to our AD. I want to input these using ldif. I have created the following ldif file with 1 attribute to add (this is on a Test AD):

```
dn: CN=tbwaUid,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=adpoctest,DC=com
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: attributeSchema
cn: tbwaUid
distinguishedName: CN=tbwaUid,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=adpoctest,DC=com
instanceType: 4
attributeId: 1.2.840.113556.1.8000.2554.2736.6320.11701.19049.45105.9072800.331707.1
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
isSingleValued: FALSE
showInAdvancedViewOnly: FALSE
adminDisplayName: tbwaUid
adminDescription: uid for tbwa systems, just a number
Description: uid for tbwa systems, just a number
omSyntax: 2
searchFlags: 1
lDAPDisplayName: tbwaUid
name: tbwaUid
objectCategory: CN=Attribute-Schema,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=adpoctest,DC=com
```

I run the following command

> ldifde -v -i -f tbwaUid.ldif -c dc=ADPOC-DC-Test DC=adpoctest,DC=com

And this is the output I get :

> Connecting to "ADPOC-DC-Test.adpoctest.com" Logging in as current user
>   using SSPI Importing directory from file "tbwaUid.ldif" Loading
>   entries 1: CN=tbwaUid,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=adpoctest,DC=com
>
> Add error on entry starting on line 2: Unwilling To Perform The server
>   side error is: 0x20c0 Schema update failed: syntax mismatch. The
>   extended server error is: 000020C0: SvcErr: DSID-032603C0, problem
>   5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 8384
>
> 0 entries modified successfully. An error has occurred in the program
>   No log files were written.  In order to generate a log file, please
>   specify the log file path via the -j option.

I have looked at several ldif example docs and I believe my syntax is correct - can anyone suggest something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure to use `-c dc=ADPOC-DC-Test DC=adpoctest,DC=com` for the right purpose? written like this it's supposed to change `ADPOC-DC-Test` by `DC=adpoctest,DC=com` inside DNs and I don't understand what you mean, but it's not causing your trouble.

Your trouble here is comming from syntax `0x20c0 Schema update failed: syntax mismatch`. Whenever you create a new attribute, you must specify its syntax. To uniquely identify the syntax among the total set of 21 syntaxes, you must specify 2 pieces of information: the OID of the syntax and a so-called OM syntax. This pair of values must be set together and correctly correlate with [Mictosoft documention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223177.aspx).

So in your case I suoppose that you should write `omSyntax: 64`.

Comment: Brilliant - Thanks mate. I had the -c there as I was replacing values in the script. I just copied the wrong command to this comment.